# Understanding spef format

Tags: parasitic-capacitance

Please help me to understand below scenario which is there inside the spef file. I have written only the snapshot, not the full text.

```
NAME_MAP

*1 foo1
*2 foo2
*3 foo3
*4 foo4
*5 foo5

D_Net *1 <value1>
*RES
…
*CAP
*1:1 *2:1 <value2>
*1:2 *3:1 <value3>
*4:a *5:b <value4>
```

I understand the first two lines of CAP section and confused about the
last line of CAP section?

Admin, please can you help tagging the right keyword to it? I do not see 'parasitics' in the list. Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain what a "spef file" is? If it is a brand name or acronym then use capital letters in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Not a SPEF expert, but it looks like it's defining a series capacitance between port a of foo4 and port b of foo5.  foo1-3 have numbered ports.